# Rails, associations, routes, controllers, kerfuffle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

My models

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :bookings
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :bookings
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :booking_time, :agent_id
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :agent
  validates_presence_of :booking_time
end
```

This is doing my head in. I want the bookings to be viewed from both the side of the Agents and the Clients, but how can the Bookings controller's index method deal with routes?

`agents/agent_id/bookings and clients/client_id/bookings` ?

Second question: Only clients create bookings, but how do I correctly maintain the relationship between bookings and agents?

```
  def create
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @booking = @client.bookings.build(params[:booking])
    @agent = Agent.find(params[:booking][:agent_id])
    @agent.bookings << @booking

    if (@booking.save and @agent.save)
      redirect_to [@client, @booking]
    else
      render :action => "new", :notice => "Booking could not be created"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

As for the first question, you simply put that in your routes (config/routes.rb):

```
resources :agents do
    resources :bookings
end

resources :clients do
    resources :bookings
end
```

This will create the nesting on your URL. More information on the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

As for the second question: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. It really depends on what you are aiming to rescue from agents and bookings. I don't know how the behavior between them works.

How are you testing your application?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not answer my question at all. I have already done what you suggest, but the question is what should the BookingsController look like to handle both requests. Do I have a index method for each case, one for requested from client side, and one when requested from agent side.

Comment: The second question is, how do I correctly maintain the three-way relationship when creating the booking objects?

Comment: Ok. BookingsController will have access to `params[:agent_id]` or `params[:client_id]`, depending on the URL. Using it, you'll be capable of setting your information on the page properly. As for the three-way relationship, it seems like you could use `has_many :clients, through: :bookings` on `Agent` and `has_many :agents, through: :bookings` on `Client`. I don't know if this is exactly what you need, but it's a way of creating three-way relationships.

Comment: OK if that's how you would do it then it's good enough for me.

Comment: Regarding the second bit, clients are unaware agents, and the opposite  is also true, at this stage. I will try and clarify again, I just want agent.bookings to be updated when I create the client.bookings. Is that how you would do it?

Comment: Oh. So it's like a kind of callback. Whenever a client creates a booking, you can set call a callback so agent.bookings will be updated. Check more about callbacks here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview

Sorry if I didn't understand at the beginning.

Comment: Well, maybe but I wouldn't expect it to be needed. Maybe I have to research it more. Thought this would be a easy question :)